# Devolver JSON con nodejs con los datos SQL (express y tedious)

Tags: javascript, sql, json, nodejs, express

Estoy intentando tranforma los datos que obtengo con mi consulta a la base de datos SQL en un json para ser enviado mediante una consulta en mi API REST.

```
const express = require('express');
const Request = require('tedious').Request;

const app = express(); // creo mi app

const db = require('./db'); // conexion a la db

....

app.get('/series',(req,res) => { 


const request = new Request( `SELECT VALOR1,VALOR2 FROM DATABASE`,(err, rowCount, rows) => {

if (err) {
console.error(err.message);
} else {
console.log(`${rowCount} row(s) returned`); // APARECE VALOR 63
};

jsonArray = [];

 rows.forEach(function (columns) {

 var rowObject ={};

   columns.forEach(function(column) {
   rowObject[column.metadata.colName] = column.value;
   });

 jsonArray.push(rowObject);
                                            
 });

                    
res.json(jsonArray);
            
}); 

db.execSql(request);

});
```

Pero el resultado es [] ( sin ningun valor dentro) , cuando realizo la petición Get ( con potman y en el navegador).
he probado a enviar con la función res.send() y el resultado es el mismo.

¿Por donde puede estar el error?

Gracias de antemano :)

PD: CODIGO DE MI DB

```
const {Connection} = require("tedious");

// Create connection to database
const config = {
  authentication: {
    options: {
      userName: "users", // update me
      password: "users" // update me
    },
    type: "default"
  },
  server: "srvdesarrollo", // update me
  options: {
    database: "users", //update me
    encrypt: false
  }
};

const connection = new Connection(config);

module.exports = connection;
```

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar el código de tu módulo `db`? Parece que el problema está en el manejo de la asincronía.

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega eso en la pregunta, no en los comentarios. Puedes hacer clic en [edit]. Saludos